# Creating RSA public/private key pair with Bouncy Castle or .Net RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

So I've messed around a bit with .Net's RSACryptoServiceProvider and Bouncy Castle to be able to create RSA key pairs and later on X509 certificates.

I'm just curious if anyone knows if there's any difference between these two codeblocks, which I think does the same thing, but the pure Bouncy Castle version takes much longer to finish.

.Net with Bouncy Castle:

```
private const int RsaKeySize = 4096;
public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GetKeyPairWithDotNet()
{
   using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(RsaKeySize))
   {
      RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(true);
      return DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsaKeyInfo);
   }
}
```

Pure Bouncy Castle:

```
private const int RsaKeySize = 4096;
public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GetKeyPair()
{
   CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
   SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
   var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(secureRandom, RsaKeySize);

   var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
   keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
   return keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
}
```

Comment: Have you tested multiple times? RSA key generation is not deterministic in time. Furthermore, it depends on how many checks are performed by the implementation (how precise is the prime number generation, is it protected against side channel attacks etc. etc.) and - not unimportantly - on the speed of the RNG. The speed of the RNG is probably also dependent on the amount of entropy within the system. In other words, this may not be so easy to answer :)

Comment: I have tested multiple times and seen that the speed varies. Though the speed is of interest since the BC version can take over one minute to finish and the .Net version hasn't as far as I have seen, I'm actually more interested if there's any difference in the keys that are created or if they can be considered "equal".

Comment: You may get better answers on the bouncy castle mailing lists. Note that the keys will be mathematically equivalent; you will be able to perform the exact same calculations with them (at least for normal/standardized use of RSA). What can differ is the quality of the generation/keys. Most of the time that won't be a big issue either. Just to be sure you could cast the private key to one with CRT parameters and check if those are about half the size of the modulus.

Comment: I cannot be absolutely sure about this but I heard BouncyCastle generates [safe primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) instead of any ordinarily large random prime number. I've confirmed this for DH parameter generation in the java implementation of BouncyCastle (seen the code) but I'm not sure if it applies here as well. Anyway, finding safe primes take a considerably longer time which could explain the increase in length since RSA key generation generates two distinct primes at the very beginning.